# Placeholders replaced for inline (Scenario) variables, not for global (Background) ones

Tags: java, gherkin, karate

I want to reuse one payload across all my scenarios of the same feature file, using Scenario Outlines and Examples that set the payload parameters correctly.
I noticed that the payload json I defined in the Background section, did not get their placeholder variables replaced.

(Java 9, Karate 0.9.0)
To showcase my issue, I boiled it down to:

```
Feature: Some Test

Background: 
  * def globalVariable = {name: <name>}

Scenario Outline: Successfully register a single valid user
  * def inlineVariable = {name: <name>}
  * print "from global : ", globalVariable
  * print "from inline : ", inlineVariable

Examples: 
  | name  |
  | 'Bob' |
```

Result:

```
16:38:00.602 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] from global :  {
  "name": "<name>"
}

16:38:00.608 [main] INFO com.intuit.karate - [print] from inline :  {
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

Would someone please explain to me, why the global json structure 'globalVariable' does not get the variables replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because placeholders work only within the `Scenario Outline`. I think it will be really confusing to support in the `Background` because you can have normal `Scenario`-s in the same `Feature`.

So please do the substitution within the `Scenario Outline` body itself - even if it means you repeat a line or two. Not a big deal IMO.

Comment: Many thanks for your fast reply, Peter. I will do as you suggest, still good to know that it is supposed to work like that